# How do I find my hadoop cluster run from docker?

Tags: docker, hadoop, localhost

I am trying to do an experiment to test different runtimes of algorithms using Hadoop with 3 nodes and pig installed. I found a docker image (fluddeni/hadoop-pig) that meets these needs and seemingly is running when checked with `docker ps`, but I can't find it on any of my ports. I am running my code on Windows and when I check where other docker images run (the docker-machine ip) on the port 9000, as indicated in my core-site.xml file I am getting no page found. Any ideas on where to find the master page for hadoop? Let me know if you need any more information!

Resources:

/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```
  <configuration>
      <property>
          <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
          <value>hdfs://3b85d55c5080:9000</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>
```

command `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                                                               NAMES
3b85d55c5080        fluddeni/hadoop-pig   "/etc/bootstrap.sh -…"   19 hours ago        Up 2 seconds        2122/tcp, 8020/tcp, 8030-8033/tcp, 8040/tcp, 8042/tcp, 8088/tcp, 9000/tcp, 10020/tcp, 19888/tcp, 49707/tcp, 50010/tcp, 50020/tcp, 50070/tcp, 50075/tcp, 50090/tcp   boring_ptolemy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you expose the port as you expect?

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 <rest image details>
```

reference:

[Publish or expose port (-p, --expose)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been struggling with this for about a week now!

Answer (score 0):

While port forwarding is one problem, another is the fact that that container ID is not consistent. You should use Docker service DNS names

Ideally, [using Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) network bridges.

Then you would always refer to `hdfs://namenode:9000`, for example

Comment: So, I have tried to change it to http://localhost:9000, but when I run the program it seems to change it back to one of the hdfs://random_string:9000. Is this normal?

Comment: `localhost` means the namenode or any client accesses itself. You need to name the container, for example using Compose or with `docker run --name`. My example assumes that you name it `namenode`, which also appears in `docker ps`